# Having curved text with html, css or JS?

Tags: javascript, css, text

[image]

How would it be possible to create curved text like this in HTML5, CSS3 or JavaScript? I am aware of transform: rotate(45deg); but that just rotates it. I have used Lettering.JS but that seems to remove any jQuery I already had on the text. The text is countdown; that works, but when used with lettering.js to make it curved, countdown does not work.

Comment: Since lettering.js didn't work perhaps an alternative will https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/24/arctext-js-curving-text-with-css3-and-jquery/ or http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/peterhry/CircleType

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with SVG.

```css
text {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 130 130">

  <path id="MyPath" fill="none" stroke="lightblue"
        d="m10,45c53,-33 96,3 96,3" />

  <text><textPath href="#MyPath">CURVE ME!</textPath></text>

</svg>
```